# R combine multiple data frames based on column names into single table

Tags: r

I have a bunch of large CSVs and they all contain the exact same columns and I need to combine them all into a single CSV, so basically appending all the data from each data frame underneath the next. Like this

Table 1

| Prop_ID | State | Pasture | Soy | Corn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | WI | 20 | 45 | 75 |
| 2 | MI | 10 | 80 | 122 |

Table 2

| Prop_ID | State | Pasture | Soy | Corn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | MN | 152 | 0 | 15 |
| 4 | IL | 0 | 10 | 99 |

Output table

| Prop_ID | State | Pasture | Soy | Corn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | WI | 20 | 45 | 75 |
| 2 | MI | 10 | 80 | 122 |
| 3 | MN | 152 | 0 | 15 |
| 4 | IL | 0 | 10 | 99 |

I have more than 2 tables to do this with, any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution, in `base R`:

```r
rbind(df1, df2)

#>   Prop_ID State Pasture Soy Corn
#> 1       1    WI      20  45   75
#> 2       2    MI      10  80  122
#> 3       3    MN     152   0   15
#> 4       4    IL       0  10   99
```

---

Or using `dplyr`:

```r
dplyr::bind_rows(df1, df2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all the csv files are in a single directory, and that these are the only files in that directory, this solution, using `data.table`, should work.

```
library(data.table)
setwd('<directory with your csv files>')
files  <- list.files(pattern = '.+\\.csv$')
result <- rbindlist(lapply(files, fread))
```

`list.files(...)` returns a vector containing the file names in a given directory, based on a pattern. Here we ask for only files containing `.csv` at the end.

`fread(...)` is a very fast file reader for `data.table`. We apply this function to each file name ( `lapply(files, fread)` ) to generate a list containing the contents of each csv. Then we use `rbindlist(...)` to combine them row-wise.